# MechanicalTurks Java library - Create HIT with a Layout ID

Tags: java, mechanicalturk

I've done a fair amount of digging but have yet to find an example. I'd like to create a new HIT with a Layout ID and a couple of parameter - how can I achieve this?

I can't seem to find the HITLayout and HITLayoutParameter data structures within the java library; the RequestorService's CreateHIT methods don't seem to accommodate this functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can't be done. The best way to accomplish something similar is to create a HIT from an HTML question as follows:

```
HITProperties props = new HITProperties("mturk.properties");
String question = FileUtil.readAsString(new File("question.html"));
HITQuestion hitQuestion = new HITQuestion();
hitQuestion.setQuestion(question);
HIT awsHit = service.createHIT(null, props.getTitle(),
            props.getDescription(), props.getKeywords(),
            question, props.getRewardAmount(),
            props.getAssignmentDuration(), props.getAutoApprovalDelay(),
            props.getLifetime(), props.getMaxAssignments(),
            props.getAnnotation(), props.getQualificationRequirements(),
            null
);
```

The question can also contain '%s' for easy String.formatting() with HIT specific sentences or words.